# How to Clear History (Clear browsing data) In Node.js Puppeteer Headless=false Chromium browser

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I am tring to delete history in headless=false browser with node.js puppeteer through below code but non of method work.

```js
await page.goto('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData');
await page.keyboard.down('Enter');
```

Second code

```js
await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft');
await page.keyboard.down('ShiftLeft');
await page.keyboard.down('Delete');
await page.keyboard.down('Enter');
```

i tried to used `.evaluateHandle()` and `.click()` function too but non of them work. if anyone know how to clear history with puppeteer please answer me.

Comment: It looks like you can get to that page but you need to go down the shadow dom to get to the button

Answer (score 43):

It is not possible to navigate to the browser settings pages (`chrome://...`) like that.

You have three options:

1. Use an incognito window (called context in puppeteer)
2. Use a command from the Chrome DevTools Protocol to clear history.
3. Restart the browser

---

### Option 1: Use an incognito window

To clear the history (including cookies and any data), you can use an "incognito" window called [BrowserContext](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#class-browsercontext) in puppeteer.

You create a context by calling [`browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#browsercreateincognitobrowsercontext). Quote from the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#browsercreateincognitobrowsercontext):

> Creates a new incognito browser context. This won't share cookies/cache with other browser contexts.

**Example**

```js
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page = await context.newPage();

// Execute your code
await page.goto('...');
// ...

await context.close(); // clear history
```

This example will create a new incognito browser window and open a page inside. From there on you can use the `page` handle like you normally would.

To clear any cookies or history inside, simply close the context via `context.close()`.

---

### Option 2: Use the Chrome DevTools Protocol to clear history

If you cannot rely on using context (as they are not supported when using extensions), you can use the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to clear the history of the browser. It has functions which are not implemented in puppeteer to reset cookies and cache. You can directly use functions from the Chrome DevTools Protocol by using a [CDPSession](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession).

**Example**

```js
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies');
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCache');
```

This will instruct the browser to clear the cookies and cache by directly calling [`Network.clearBrowserCookies`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-clearBrowserCookies) and [`Network.clearBrowserCache`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-clearBrowserCache).

---

### Option 3: Restart the browser

If both approaches are not feasible, you can alway restart the browser, by closing the old instance and creating a new one. This will clear any stored data.

Comment: Thanks for reply and solution. but Incognito Browser not support chrome extension.

Comment: @ZilviaSmith Is it an option to restart the browser?

Comment: Yes. restart is option but some time we need to do clear history & this is important part for puppeteer and chromium.

Comment: @ZilviaSmith I added a second option which shows how to clear browser cache and cookies :)

Comment: Not work for clear history.  page.deleteCookie(); and page.setCacheEnabled(false); is best option then use dev tool.

Comment: @ZilviaSmith What exactly do you mean by history then? Cookies? Cache?

Comment: i want to Clear browsing data ( Browsing history, download history, cookies, cache, password, fill data)  (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData) => advance tab

Comment: @ZilviaSmith The code from my answer should do exactly that (download history, password fill, etc. is not present in headless mode). What is not working then?

Comment: i am using headless=false.

Comment: @ZilviaSmith Sorry, forgot that.. In that case you can only do a full reset by closing the old window and relaunching (added the option to the answer).

Comment: How important it is to detach the client? any side effects?